# Why autocomplete in PhpStorm show me wrong router-address?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm

I need some help.

I created resource router like this:

```
Route::resource('/consultation', 'Clinic\EditConsultation',[
            'as'=>'clinic.edit',
            'parameters' => [
                'consultation' => 'consultation_id'
            ]
        ]);
```

And true router is `clinic.edit.consultation.create/show/etc`, but autocomplete in PhpStorm show only `consultation.create/show/etc`.

Could you help me with my problem?

P.S. Laravel 5.5, PhpStorm 2017.3

Comment: PhpStorm does not offer any completion help for Laravel routes. Such completion assistance comes from "Laravel Plugin" plugin, which is a third party plugin. That plugin does not understand `as` (or `names`) parameter for `::resource()` method.

Comment: The possible workaround -- surround it with `Route::group()` call where you can provide `as` parameter. Something like this: `Route::group(['as' => 'clinic.edit.'], function () { Route::resource('/consultation', 'Clinic\EditConsultation',['parameters' => ['consultation' => 'consultation_id']]); });` **P.S.** It will give completion help .. but not sure how it will be performed in actual code / live site. Test it. Maybe it's not worth it (looks too complicated just for IDE completion help). In any case -- https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-laravel-plugin/issues

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, I chose your case. `Route::group(['as' => 'clinic.edit.']` is work.